# Expect script to run a shell script in remote server

Tags: expect

I am trying to create an expect script to execute a shell script with arguments in remote server, however the script is not getting executed and it is returning the $ prompt in remote server. Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh username@servername
expect "password:"
send "abc\r"
expect "$ "
send "cd /home/abc\r"
send "./script.sh --status arg1 arg2\r"
```

-- here the script is located in home/abc directory and the shell script ./script needs to be executed with the parameter --status arg1 arg2. Also i need to save the contents of ./script.sh --status arg1 arg2 in a file and email it. Can the mailx command works inside a expect script or i need to call this expect script from a another shell script. Please assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something quick and risky:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password your_password
set timeout 100

spawn scp -q /home/abc/script.sh username@server:/tmp
expect  {
"(yes/no)?"          {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
"password:"          {send "$password\r"; exp_continue}
"lost connection"    {puts "ERROR: lost connection"}
"No route to host"   {puts "ERROR: no route to host"}
timeout              {puts "ERROR: timeout"}
}

spawn ssh username@server
expect  {
 "(yes/no)?"              {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
 "password:"              {send "$password\r"; exp_continue}
 "username@server"        {send "sh /tmp/script.sh; exit\r";exp_continue }
 "password for username:" {send "$password\r"; exp_continue}
 "password:"              {send "$password\r"; exp_continue}
 "lost connection"        {puts "ERROR: lost connection"}
 "No route to host"       {puts "ERROR: no route to host"}
 timeout                  {puts "ERROR: timeout"}
 }
```

Variable `password` put there to run script automatically. 
Also you see `"$password\r"` as reference to set variable.

`spawn scp -q /home/abc/script.sh username@server:/tmp` copies your script to /tmp in remote server. `-q` flag disables the progress meter.

`spawn ssh username@server` connects to your server. 
`sh /tmp/script.sh` runs script copied in the previous step.

Also, I send e-mails using [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/)